# App Crashes while Implementing Google Api Client and Location Listener

Tags: java, android, location

I am trying to make an app that traces that path of the user on google maps using public void onLocationChanged(Location location) but every time I try to implement the location listener my app crashes. Here is my code.. please let me know if you see anything that needs to be fixed. Thanks!

Android Manifest file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.carthage.haag.jacob.homework_application_android">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyD-2jUwPWvPzHmsdIiYuW9tLarxYe6AQwE" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="edu.carthage.haag.jacob.homework_application_android.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">

    </activity>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

Here is my MapsActivity.java file

```html
package edu.carthage.haag.jacob.homework_application_android;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private final static int MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> points; //added
    Polyline line; //added
    private Context context;
    private static final long INTERVAL = 5000; //1 minute
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 minute
    private static final float SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 0.05F; //quarter of a meter
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private float LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 1;
    private long LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 100;
    //gets the initial gps coordinates
    private Location mLastLocation;

    String locationProvider;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {

//        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
//                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
//
//        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
//        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        points = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); //added
        context = MapsActivity.this;

        //createLocationRequest();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT); //added
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camer
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); //you already have this

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("New Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        points.add(latLng); //added

        redrawLine(); //added
    }

    private void redrawLine() {

        mMap.clear();  //clears all Markers and Polylines

        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            LatLng point = points.get(i);
            options.add(point);
        }
        //addMarker(); //add Marker in current position
        line = mMap.addPolyline(options); //add Polyline
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    //    @Override
//    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
//        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
//        switch (requestCode) {
//            case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
//                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//                    }
//
//                } else {
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    finish();
//                }
//                break;
//        }
//    }

}
```

Comment: where and how does it crash - pretty important info I think

Comment: and why is this tagged as javascript?

Comment: Post your stacktrace when you are getting this crash..

Comment: The program crashes at.....

Comment: if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

Comment: "GoogleApiClient is not connected yet."  That's your problem

Comment: I did call GoogleApiClient.connect() in my onCreate() method.. Based on the recommendations below I will attempt to put GoogleApiClient.connect() in my onStart() method.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

as per stack-trace, it seems you are trying to access location before GoogleAPI client is connected.

Hence, you should request for location when it is connected. The same can be implemented :

```
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
```

Or you can request location updates  **onConnected** method.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

You haven't done what I had said, find the complete code which I tested :
See the **line number 103** and **line number 179**

```
package edu.carthage.haag.jacob.homework_application_android;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.devop.aashish.androiddemo.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private final static int MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
    private static final long INTERVAL = 5000; //1 minute
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 minute
    private static final float SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 0.05F; //quarter of a meter
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Polyline line; //added
    String locationProvider;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> points; //added
    private Context context;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private float LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 1;
    private long LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 100;
    //gets the initial gps coordinates
    private Location mLastLocation;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {

//        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
//                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
//
//        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
//        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        points = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); //added
        context = MapsActivity.this;

        //createLocationRequest();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT); //added
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Google API not connected yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); //you already have this

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("New Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        points.add(latLng); //added

        redrawLine(); //added
    }

    private void redrawLine() {

        mMap.clear();  //clears all Markers and Polylines

        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            LatLng point = points.get(i);
            options.add(point);
        }
        //addMarker(); //add Marker in current position
        line = mMap.addPolyline(options); //add Polyline
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Google API connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Google API not connected yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    //    @Override
//    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
//        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
//        switch (requestCode) {
//            case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
//                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//                    }
//
//                } else {
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    finish();
//                }
//                break;
//        }
//    }
}
```

Comment: I added mGoogleApiClient.connect(); to my onStart() method and then tried to  call LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this); and the app crashed again. I have updated my code above with new stack trace and MapsActivity.java file. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Had you requested FusedLocation.requestLocationUpdates in onConnected method ? If your app still crashes put the complete crash log as comment.

Comment: Yes, I request FusedLocation.requestLocationUpdates in onConnected method.. and my crash log is in the below comment

Comment: Also I cannot add my crash log, to many characters for a comment

Comment: I had modified my answer with complete code. I tested your code and I also got same crash, then I incorporated if condition to check connected status of google api client before requesting location updates and did same in onConnected method. Hope it works for you. Revert back if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Connect google api client in `onstart()` rather than in `oncreate ()`

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
```

And Initilize the googleApi client in `oncreate()` using this method and call in onCreate()

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I added mGoogleApiClient.connect(); to my onStart() method and then tried to call LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGo‌​ogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this); and the app crashed again. I have updated my code above with new stack trace and MapsActivity.java file. Let me know what you think

Comment: add logcat please

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help, I was able to figure out my problem. The issue was that I was not utilizing the onConnected() method where ocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this); is called. Now that I made the change everything works!